# PowerPoint how to create multiple window layout?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I am trying to create a PowerPoint file that has

```
----------------------------------------
|                           |          |
|                           |          |
|                           |          |
|                           |__________|
|                           |          |
|                           |          |
|                           |          |
|___________________________|__________|
|                                      |
|______________________________________|
```

Each of the rectangles would be doing something different

the big one would show a PDF (or a PPTX)
the top right will show a clock with the date and weather
the middle right will be a photo slide show from a group of images (or another PPTX)

the bottom would be a news ticker

I dont know how to even create this layout in PowerPoint

I inserted Object and selected from File and I opened an existing (powerpoint)Photo Album and sized that to be the middle right square. But the album will not automatically rotate the image (dont know how to do that either)

I would appreciate any feedback on how to solve this without buying DataPoint or similar add on's (Free Ad On's are OK)

Comment: Rotate the images manually outside of powerpoint

Comment: Also can you not draw the boxes in the required layout yourself?

Comment: @Burgi Thank you. How do you rotate the images manually? The powerpoint will be on a Intel Compute Stick and on a TV. No keyboard and mouse will be available to click the slide.

Comment: In the OS folder where the image files are located, rotate them there then import your photo album when creating the presentation.